# Recompiling Application From apk to source code

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, recompile, apktool

I try to extract apk to Source code by apktool. Then i want to change the colors and i try to screen the app from my mobile and get the HEX CODE  color and searching on "Find By Files" on notepad++ but i cant find the color. I found a file named colors.xml But. the Hex iis very long.

[image: Picture]

Can any one tell me how to change the color and where is the background color here?

Answer (score 0):

It is a 4byte Hexadecimal color code! Probably in CMYK encoding.
Sorry I was wrong about the CMYK, didn't know about the alpha chanel - But I have wanted to know how to make things transparent, but all editors have used the standard 3byte RGB encoding!
Thanks to Zach for the clarification.

Comment: You need to have a more descriptive answer

Answer (score 0):

The format there is aRGB, so the first byte is the alpha channel, or transparency. The color from the highlighted line is #323232 (dark grey) with a transparency of 50%.